# sklearn: Why is score on a random forest comprising of one tree (so) different from the score computed directly on that tree?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a multi-class classification problem with 20 classes and about 90 features. I am using the RandomForestClassifier from the scikit-learn python package (ver 0.18.1). Here's what I see:

```
> rf1 = RandomForestClassifier(max_features=0.5, n_estimators=1)
> rf1.fit(X_train, y_train)
> print rf1.score(X_test, y_test), rf1.score(X_train, y_train)
0.27868852459 0.740046838407

> print rf1.estimators_[0].score(X_test, y_test), rf1.estimators_[0].score(X_train, y_train)
0.0300546448087 0.0140515222482

> rf1
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
        max_depth=None, max_features=0.5, max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        n_estimators=1, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
        verbose=0, warm_start=False)

> rf1.estimators_
[DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
             max_features=0.5, max_leaf_nodes=None,
             min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
             min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
             presort=False, random_state=2134571240, splitter='best')]
```

How can these scores be different? I have a single tree in my RF classifier!
Any pointers will be very helpful.

I plotted the feature_importances_ for rf1 and rf1.estimators_[0] and they are identical, which is exactly what I expect. But the scores are so different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. Turns out the DecisionTree rf1.estimators_[0] considers classes from 0 to 19, whereas the rf1 classifier considers classes from 1 to 20, as in the original input. If I add one to the output of the DecisionTree classifier, the outputs are identical, as expected.